# How Can I Compare A 4 Digit Variable To A List Of 4 Digit Numbers And Determine If They Have The Exact Same Numbers, Regardless Of Order?

Tags: python

I have been trying to create a program that will break a 4 digit code by listing all possible codes. The code, 1234 and 4321 will both work as they have the same numbers. Just as 7125 and 2157 will work.

I have tried comparing the variable with the numbers in the list, but have only been able to do it with, for example, 1234 as the variable and 1234 as the number in the list.

```py
codes1example = [1240, 1241, 0214]
variable1example = 4120
```

I am not on my normal computer so I cannot post the comparing code, but it is probably easy to make.

With my original code, it would disregard any numbers in the list that is the same as the variable. But I cannot get past this, I cannot make it so it does not matter the order.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WUse the set structure:

```
for n in codes1example:
   if not set(str(variable1example)).symmetric_difference(set(str(n))):
      print(variable1example, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to convert the `int` to `str` and sort them and then do the comparison.

**Ex:**

```
codes1example = [1240, 1241, 2014]
variable1example = 4120

temp = map(sorted, (map(str, codes1example)))
if sorted(str(variable1example)) in temp:
    print("Ok!")
else:
    print("No!!!")

#-->Ok!
```

Comment: This is good, but you need to allow for codes with leading zeros. e.g. 0214 in the example should be converted to ‘0214’. You could do that with `str(214).zfill(4)` or `'{0:04d}'.format(214)`. As a cool but hard-to-understand option you could simply put `'{0:04d}'.format` in place of `str` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
codes1example = [1240, 1241, 214]
variable1example = 4120

def matchable(code):
     return sorted(str(code).zfill(4))

[c for c in codes1example if matchable(c) == matchable(variable1example)]

# [1240, 214]
```

This converts each item into a strong with left zero padding, then sorts the digits in the string to standardize them, then compares those. After sorting, these will actually be lists of digits as strings, but the comparison should work fine.

Note that I had to drop the leading zero from 214 when entering it as an integer, because the leading 0 causes it to be interpreted as an octal literal (0214 == decimal 140). I assume your real code has proper bits that should be interpreted as 4-digit decimal numbers. If you are storing your numbers as strings instead, you can skip the `str()` step.